# Is there a way to do automation testing for a Flutter desktop application without image processing?

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, flutter-test

The current dilemma is clicking through a Flutter desktop application. We are able to click through the desktop application using image processing with PyAutoGui but this comes with a scalability limitation.

The ideal solution would be some sort of software that can click on elements by element ID rather than image recognition. Similar to how Selinum works on web applications.

Thanks, any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider flutter driver?
https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

It will be like automation click and something else

Comment: We have not looked at Flutter Driver yet. We will check this out as a new prospect. At a glance, I see mobile support but I do not see desktop application support. This does not mean it does not support it but will dive deeper. Thank you, Taz for pointing this out :)